How to config nginx location to show a welcome page?
On my server, the directory structure is like:
/data/
  - index.html
  - foo/

My requirement is:

When only domain name is given, http://mycompany.com, it should show a page of index.html
When path foo is given, http://mycompany.com/foo, it should show a list of file and sub-folders data /data/foo.

My download.conf is like:
    server {
        listen       8080 default;
        root   /data;
        autoindex on;
        # here how to configure locations
    }

I suppose this is a basic use case, but I am really new to nginx.
